# Creating a column with the difference between 02 datetimes - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataset with 02 datetime columns and I want to calculate what is the difference between both and create a new column with that difference:

```
Column 1               Column 2
2020-02-14 01:16:32     2020-02-14 08:38:59  
2019-12-24 00:09:29     2019-12-24 02:51:38
2020-02-17 00:39:02     2020-02-17 02:17:25
```

The idea is to have Column 2 - Column 1 and the difference set in hours.
I didnt find a way to do that they way I need and I tried to to just a basic calculation, one minus the other, but it didn`t work so I was hoping someone could help with this task

thanks

Comment: What happens if you try `df['Column 2'] - df['Column 1']`?

Comment: I have something like this:
0        -1 days +06:21:30
1        -2 days +06:23:58
2        -1 days +20:09:57
3        -1 days +23:59:37

However it doesn`t make much sense as I need this in hours and this result to be added as a different column

Answer (score 1):

Difference the two columns (after converting to datetime), then use the `dt` accessor method to get the total seconds difference of the [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html).  Convert to hours by dividing by 3600 (60 seconds per minute, 60 minutes per hour). Assign the result back to the dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Column 1": ["2020-02-14 01:16:32", "2019-12-24 00:09:29", "2020-02-17 00:39:02"],
    "Column 2": ["2020-02-14 08:38:59", "2019-12-24 02:51:38", "2020-02-17 02:17:25"]}
)

time_delta = pd.to_datetime(df['Column 2']) - pd.to_datetime(df['Column 1'])
>>> df.assign(hours_difference=time_delta.dt.total_seconds().div(3600))
              Column 1             Column 2  hours_difference
0  2020-02-14 01:16:32  2020-02-14 08:38:59          7.374167
1  2019-12-24 00:09:29  2019-12-24 02:51:38          2.702500
2  2020-02-17 00:39:02  2020-02-17 02:17:25          1.639722
```

Answer (score 0):

using numpy and and `timedelta64`

```
# import numpy as np
df['diff'] = (df['Column 2'] - df['Column 1']) / np.timedelta64(1,'h') # h = hour.

print(df)

             Column 1            Column 2      diff
0 2020-02-14 01:16:32 2020-02-14 08:38:59  7.374167
1 2019-12-24 00:09:29 2019-12-24 02:51:38  2.702500
2 2020-02-17 00:39:02 2020-02-17 02:17:25  1.639722
```